# PDO: how to save packed IPv6 representation into the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ipv6

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_IPs` (
  `IP6` decimal(16,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IP6`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

We want to insert an IPv6 address into this table:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'secret';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'ERROR (1-CONNECT) ACCOUNT NOT READY'.$e->getMessage();
    return false;
  }

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_IPs SET IP6=:IP6
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP6=:IP6";

//Here we get an array of 16 unsigned bytes
//representing the IPv6 address
$IP6 = inet_pton("fe80::2e0:4cff:feb0:f8d");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

//the problem is here
//tried PDO::PARAM_LOB, but it doesn't work
$stmt->bindParam(':IP6', $IP6, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result === false)
{
    print $stmt->errorInfo();
    return false;
}

$sql = "SELECT IP6 FROM users_IPs;";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$IP = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);

//string(1) "0" <- ? Just 1 byte
var_dump($IP);
//PHP Warning:  inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value
$IP =  inet_ntop($IP);
//outputs: bool(false)
var_dump($IP);
```

In the database the value for this column is "0". So, it seems that PDO doesn't save $IP6 as an array of bytes, but converts it in some way. Which make the value incorrect.

Comment: You cannot use `:IP6` twice in a query. Use `:IP6A` and `:IP6B` instead and bind twice.

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you can if emulation mode is turned on

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Tried it, but the values is still "0"

Comment: @My Common Sense: Yes, that's true: "You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.": http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Btw, ipv6 is 128 bits, not obvious how you want to fit it into 16 digits number.

Comment: @zerkms Divide 128 by 8 = 16 bytes

Comment: @user4035 "Divide 128 by 8 = 16 bytes" --- this makes very little sense.

Comment: 16 bytes <> 16 decimal digits

Comment: @YourCommonSense True. In this case what is the correct database type for it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thx, I'll try VARBINARY(16)